# AspectJ not working for class that implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have the following class:

```
@Component
public class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
        System.out.println("Error handling!"); 
    }
}
```

And I have the following aspect:

```
@Before("execution(* org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleUncaughtException(java.lang.Throwable, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object...)) && "
        + "args(ex, method, params) && target(myapplication.exception.handler.AsyncExceptionHandler)")
public void asyncExceptionHandlerHandleUncaughtExceptionBefore(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
    System.out.println("Aspect OK!"); 
}
```

I need this aspect due to a standard way to log in to my application.
Today, this class of aspects has a lot of aspects that are working!
Only this aspect is not working!

### Question:

1. I guess is not possible to intercept the AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler implementation (an 
   interceptor). Is that?
2. Something related to varags `params`?

Comment: Without having tried, your pointcut and advice declaration looks fine to me, also the varargs part. I am an AOP expert, though, not a Spring user. But what I do know about Spring AOP is the documented limitation that you cannot apply aspects upon other aspects. Having said that, I have no idea how exception handlers are actually implemented in Spring. If AOP is used internally to somehow wrap them or so, you might indeed hit mentioned limitation. But this is pure speculation. `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` does reside in a package named `org.springframework.aop.interceptor`, though.

Comment: If you have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me on GitHub, I would like to clone it and look/debug around a bit just because it is an interesting question. Maybe then I can deny or confirm something for you.